# Invalid RPC message origin when loading Google+button script in ie9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-api

I'm getting the following error when loading a Google Plus One script:

```
Invalid rpc message origin. https://apis.google.com vs http://10.0.1.59:3001
```

My code:

```
load('//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js')
```

where load is the following module:

```
module.exports = function addScript(src) {
  var script = document.createElement('script')
  script.type = 'text/javascript'
  script.src = src
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  return {
    onLoad: function(fn) {
      script.addEventListener('load', function() {
        fn(null, script)
      })
      script.addEventListener('error', function() {
        fn(new Error('Failed loading script: ' + src))
      })
      return script
    },
    script: script
  }
}
```

How can I avoid this message?

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Answer (score -1):

I got this error in FF and loading the whole page again (ctrl+F5, I've forgot the term) solved the error.